# Text rotation in cairo surface

Tags: c++, c, linux, graphics, cairo

I need to draw some text in vertical direction using cairo. With the following code I'm not able to achieve the required angle, or In other words, I'm not able to figure out what cairo_rotate(cr, angle); interface expects in angle parameter. The sample code and output is given below.

```
cairo_surface_t *surface;
cairo_t *cr;

surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_A1, 400, 400);
cr = cairo_create(surface);

cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
cairo_select_font_face(cr, "Sans", CAIRO_FONT_SLANT_NORMAL,
                       CAIRO_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL);
cairo_set_font_size(cr, 40.0);


cairo_move_to(cr, 100, 50.0);
cairo_rotate(cr, 90);

cairo_show_text(cr, "Sample Text");

cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

cairo_destroy(cr);
cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
```

[image]

Comment: Please, have a look at [SO: Understanding cairo_rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22960353/7478597). Btw., it seems that `cairo_rotate()` expects radians (instead of degrees). (I saw this in the linked sample but could not find a doc. to clarify this.)

Comment: Fix: I found one: [`cairo_rotate()`](https://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Transformations.html#cairo-rotate) - angle is given in radians.

Comment: @Scheff Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Scheff pointed out in comment, `void cairo_rotate (cairo_t *cr,double angle);` expects radians, not **angle**. Its easy to be getting mislead from parameter name if you are not focusing on documentation.

Coming to the answer, If you need to rotate a text in some angle, you need to find the equivalent radians first using the given formula.

> α(radians) = α(degrees) × π / 180°

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I believe, you mis-worded a bit: It expects the angle in radians but not in degrees. (But, of course, it expects an **angle**.) ;-)